# How to access variable in other class

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to access a variable in another class, but it's giving me the error

> Property 'itemType' not found on object of type '__strong id'

Basically, I init the class with this

```
 GameMsgs *warningMsg = [[GameMsgs alloc]initWithItem:@"remove_village-object-warning" andCallingMethod:self];
```

and in GameMsgs...

```
- (id)initWithItem:(NSString*)itemTypeP andCallingMethod:(id)callingMethod
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        sharedInstance = [SKGame sharedInstance];

        myCallingMethod = callingMethod;

...
```

But when I try to access a variable in myCallingMethod, I get the above error. This is how I'm trying to access it...

```
 Text *valueT = [[Text alloc] initWithText:[[myCallingMethod.itemType objectForKey:@"templateKingdomObject"] objectForKey:@"removeCost"] withX:70 withY:60 withSize:14 withFieldWidth:100 withFieldHeight:30 withColour:0xffffff withFont:@"MarkerFelt-Thin"];
```

With the error just at the start of itemType.

myCallingMethod is a type of id.

I presume this is something obvious, but I'm new to Obj-c still.

Comment: **Read** (and preferably understand) the error message. Or at least google it, that shouldn't hurt, should it.

Comment: Two existing answers below are good, just want to point something out. Inside your `GameMsgs` init method you make reference to `[SKGame sharedInstance]`. This is bad practice. I'm assuming you're keeping a strong reference to this object, but the whole point of singletons and sharedInstances is that they're global and don't go away. I'd suggest not having a sharedInstance ivar in your GameMsgs class, and when you need access to it just call `[SKGame sharedInstance]` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable callingMethod is of type "id". In the land of Obj-C "id" doesn't mean anything other than an address to basically anything. The compiler doesn't know the real type of the callingMethod object and thus assumes it doesn't have any methods. You can fix this in two ways:

Changing your method declaration to incorporate an actual class for your "callingMethod" variable

```
- (id)initWithItem:(NSString *)itemTypeP andCallingMethod:(YourClass *)callingMethod
```

Or by casting to your own type where you need it.

```
Text *valueT = [[Text alloc] initWithText:[[((YourClass *)myCallingMethod).itemType objectForKey:@"templateKingdomObject"] objectForKey:@"removeCost"] withX:70 withY:60 withSize:14 withFieldWidth:100 withFieldHeight:30 withColour:0xffffff withFont:@"MarkerFelt-Thin"];
```

But that's ugly.

This is all assuming that your variable "callingMethod" is of one type, otherwise look into [protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `myCallingMethod is a type of id`. What this means is that `myCallingMethod` could be any type of object. That means that the compiler doesn't know what it is so it doesn't know that your dot notation is correct.

You can either use the traditional method notation (then the compiler will just trust you and throw an exception at runtime if you're wrong). Or, change your definition of `myCallingMethod` to use an actual Class name (one which defines the property `itemType`).